# Selenium IDE - stopping execution of test case at successfull test

Tags: selenium-ide

I would like to stop the execution of a test case if a condition is true.

So vice versa of assert. Something like BreakIfElementPresent

Possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: You can use pause command may be or perform a single assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I have used gotoIf statements to fail some of my tests for logging.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>link=New Query</td>
    <td>isPresent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>${isPresent} == true</td>
    <td>querycreationtestpass</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>&quot;Test failed because new query wasnt created&quot;</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>label</td>
    <td>querycreationtestpass</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This also shows up in the logs as

> "Test failed because new query wasn't created"

which allows me to diagnose what went wrong